# iOS Cocoapods Documentation Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods-1.1.1

In Xcode 8, Apple integrated a comment documentation generator plugin. Select your method or function (Swift) and Menu -> Editor -> Structure -> Add Documentation.

Example for Swift:

```
    /// Get the elevation of a point.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - point: An array of one point @[lat, lon] or a dictionary @{"lat":..., "lon":...}.
///   - completionHandler: The completion handler to call when the load request is complete. 
///     This completion handler takes the following parameters:
///
///                              result: elevation in the same type as the input (point)
///                              error:  An error object that indicates why the request failed, or nil if the request was successful.
```

Is this recognized by CocoaPods for Swift librairies?

Comment: What do you mean by "recognised"?

Comment: When you create a pod lib on CocoaPods, it generate a documentation with the comments above the method. I would like to know if someone have tested this for Swift librairies.